# Are there any repeats of a number (eg repeat of 86 is 8686) that are perfect squares?

Tags: number-theory

When we repeat a number, i.e. write it twice in a row, we get another number with even no. of digits. 
For e.g. repeating '86' gives us the number '8686'
Is there any such repeat number which is a perfect square. How many such perfect squares are there?

Comment: Flagged for moderator attention. As noted by @RahulSharma and confirmed by a quick search, the question is part of the [PROMYS 2017](http://promys.org/program/applications) [application problem set](http://promys.org/sites/promys.org/files/assets/Problems2017.pdf) which is still ongoing with a submission deadline of April 1st 2017. To the OP: this site doesn't condone cheating.

Comment: This is also on other PROMYS application problem set - I am currently doing the 2023 problem set and this comes up as Q2... @dxiv

Answer (score 5):

Note that repeats of a number are of the form $(10^n+1)x$, where $x$ is the integer that is repeated and $n$ is the number of digits of $x$. Hence repeated numbers are divisible by $10^n +1$ where $n$ is the number of digits of the number that is repeated.

To have a repeated number which is also a square we need to find $n$ such that the product of primes with **odd powers** in the prime decomposition of $10^n +1$ has value less than $10^n$. Intuitively, the number which is repeated must 'make up' for the odd power primes in the decomposition of $10^n+1.$

This observation proves that there are no perfect square repeated numbers with $4$ digits as $101$ does not satisfy the above requirements ($101$ is prime!). Likewise there are no $6$ digit perfect square repeated numbers as $1001=7\cdot11\cdot13$. To generalise this method for arbitrary $n$ we need knowledge on the prime decomposition of $10^n+1$ in general. I'm not sure if anything is known about this!

Hope this helps!

Edit: Searching online I've found that
$$10^{11}+1 = 11^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 4093 \cdot 8779.$$
To form a repeated perfect square, we need $k$ such that $k^2  \cdot 23 \cdot 4093 \cdot 8779 = k^2\cdot826446281$ has $11$ digits. $k=10$ works.

Hence $(10^{11}+1)\cdot100 \cdot 23 \cdot 4093 \cdot 8779=8264462810082644628100$ is a repeated number and a perfect square!

Checking this on wolfram alpha shows that this number is indeed a square. It is the square of 
$$90909090910.$$

Note that our choice of $k$ was arbitrary. If we instead chose $k = 9$, we arrive at the square repeated number
$$6694214876166942148761 =  81818181819^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of how to find such numbers or prove that they do not exist. I've left some details to be filled in.

Repeating a two digit number, as you have done, leaves a number divisible by $101$  which is a three digit prime, and can't occur as a squared factor of the result (because the square is larger than the number you are interested in).

Duplicating an $n$ digit number leaves something which is divisible by $10^n+1$, and the same observation applies so long as there are no squared factors of $10^n+1$. On the other hand if $10^n+1=p^2q$ then $(10^n+1)q=p^2q^2$

---

I've deleted what was here because it was wrong. Instead modify the above to choose $t$ so that $r=t^2q$ has $n$ digits. Then $(10^n+1)r=p^2t^2q^2=(ptq)^2$.

Again, you should be able to find a solution with $p=7$ (the lowest available prime), but this will be larger than the solution Zestylemonzi has with $p=11$.

Answer (score 1):

There’s a nice trick regarding the decomposition of $10^n+1$ when we want to find a square prime factor.

First,
$$1-z^n = (1-z)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+\dots+z^0).$$
Set $z=-10$ and $n=2k+1$ giving,
$$1-(-10)^{2k+1} = \left(1-(-10)\right)\left((-10)^{2k}+(-10)^{2k-1}+\dots+(-10)^0\right).$$
Simplify using even and odds powers. So,
$$10^{2k+1} + 1 = 11(10^{2k}-10^{2k-1}+\dots+10^0).$$
Thus $11$ is a divisor of $10^{2k+1}+1$. Now look at the remainders of the second factor when divding by $11$
\begin{align}\left(10^{2k}-10^{2k-1}+\dots+10^0\right)\bmod{11} &= (-1)^{2k}-(-1)^{2k-1}+\dots+(-1)^0 \\
&= 1 + 1 + \dots + 1 \\
&= 2k+1.\end{align}
So when $11$ divides $2k+1$, $11^2$ divides $10^{2k+1} + 1$ and we have our square factor! Note that these are not the only $10^n+1$ with square factors, but the ones with $11^2$ are easy to find.