# Is there any repeats of numbers (eg repeat of 67 is 6767) that are perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is interesting question  of RMO Mock and asked in PRMOYS 2017.

When we repeat a number, i.e. write it twice in a row, we get another number  For e.g. repeating '67' gives us the number '6767' Is there any such repeat number which is a perfect square. How many such perfect squares are there?

> My approach is that to find any number lets suppose a , we need to multiply with ( 10^n +1) where n is number of digit in a. eg 67 * (10^2+1) = 6767.This will give us repetition,,  lets suppose repeat to be b.

> (10^n+1) can never be perfect square hence we will spilt it into (p^2xk) and k will be grouped with a
> like => b = p^2x(k*a).

after doing this i am unable to think and come up with solution.
If anyone can provide me with solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any repeats of a number (eg repeat of 86 is 8686) that are perfect squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172935/are-there-any-repeats-of-a-number-eg-repeat-of-86-is-8686-that-are-perfect-squ) - found as the first result of a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=repeat+perfect+squares).

Comment: @John, Yes, but I changed the tags so my close vote is non gold.